# Control image data memory in cv::Mat

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, buffer

I'm building a pipeline for an image treatment project using OpenCv.
In one of my classes I generate an image:

`m_RGBMatData = cv::Mat(cv::Size(1824, 948), CV_16U);`

and I want to save its data in a buffer. The pointer I use on my buffer is called `m_host_Rgb`
This works when I do

`memcpy(m_host_Rgb, m_RGBMatData.data, 1824 * 948 * 3 * 2);` => (16bits RGB image!)

But I would like to avoid the `memcpy` function in oder to improve performance. I tried this:

`m_host_Rgb = m_RGBMatData.data;`

But I think the `cv::Mat` object deletes its memory when is out of scope.
Is there a way to keep the `cv::Mat` object's memory until next call? or something like that?

thanks!

Comment: You could just keep the mat alive too until the next call... Or you could have the mat use user-provided memory afaik.

Comment: also you need to specify the number of channels: CV_16UC3

Comment: @MaxLanghof, thanks, but the image will be used by classes that do not necessarily use OpenCV, this is why I don't want to keep the Mat alive

Comment: see following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906437/opencv-matrix-into-shared-memory). It describes how to use shared memory. It does use a **memcpy** call but my gues is that you would need to do it once only to initiate the pipe line

Comment: Just create a [`Mat`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a51615ebf17a64c968df0bf49b4de6a3a) header around a buffer.... no copies needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to manage the memory yourself, then as Dan Mašek's comment [suggested](https://answers.opencv.org/question/45105/use-allocated-buffer-for-mat-data-pointer/), you can use [a different constructor for cv::Mat](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-mat):

```
#include <cstdint>

uint16_t* m_host_Rgb = new uint16_t[1824 * 948 * 3];
cv::Mat m_RGBMatData(1824, 948, CV_16UC3, (void*) m_host_Rgb);
```

Even after `m_RGBMatData` goes out of scope, you can still use `m_host_Rgb`, because you are managing its memory yourself.